# How do you undo the 'destroy' command in cycle2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm trying to activate cycle2 on a list of images when the window gets too small to fit all the images and show all the images when the browser is big enough to display them. (#bignav is element containing the images.) I did some testing and the function stops working after I destroy it as it wont start it again. Is their another way of going about it? Could I activate it and deactivate by changing the name of the class?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 1325) {
        $('#bignav').cycle();
    } else {
        $('#bignav').cycle('destroy');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Re-initialize it...**

```
$('#bignav').cycle('reinit');
```

They have an api [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/).